# How to parse the output of the last executed target in Phing

Tags: php, exec, target, phing

Just wondering. How am I going to get the last executed Target from phing output?

I am using exec() from php. Im trying to parse the output and get only the last executed Target.

.....
....

`[42] =>     [mkdir] Created dir: /var/www/html/SampleProject/output`

`[43] =>`

`[44] => SampleProject > svn:tag:export:`

`[45] =>`

`[46] =>      [echo] Force exporting SampleProject`

`[47] =>      [echo] svn export --force --non-interactive --no-auth-cache ..... .`

`[48] => Execution of target "svn:tag:export" failed for the following reason: Task exited with code 1`

`[49] => [phingcall] Task exited with code 1`

`[50] =>        [if] Error in IfTask`

`[51] => Execution of target "scm:tag:checkout" failed for the following reason: Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.`

`[52] =>`

`[53] => BUILD FAILED`

`[54] => Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.`

`[55] => Total time: 0.2716 seconds`

`[56] =>`

I need to get all the results of SampleProject > svn:tag:export which is from index 44 onwards.

Comment: Are you *always* looking for the output of `svn:tag:export:`, or are you looking for any failed target?

Comment: Hi chris, actually both. Im not sure how am I going to get this last executed target. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're running Phing *from* PHP, but you may have a specialized use case. To get the output of a single target, I'd recommend calling Phing directly on that target. To capture errors, as long as Phing properly prints its errors to STDERR, you can do something like `phing ... 2> errors.log`.

Comment: hi chris, thank you for the inputs, i really appreciate it! In my case, i need not to specifically call the target, I need the phing run all the targets, from end to end. And if an error was found, I can have a script wherein it will get the log of the failing target and its failed result.